# How to turn Defender back on after using O&O ShutUp

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender

How to turn Windows Defender back on, after disabling it in O&O Shut Up 10?
I switched it back in OOSU but it still doesn't work.
I also tried using different tutorials, but usually nothing happens, or I get error 577: Windows cannot verify the digital signature... etc...

Thanks alot for any help!

Answer (score 1):

This batch script solved the problem:
https://pastebin.com/0NxF7kCd

```
rem USE AT OWN RISK AS IS WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND !!!!!

reg delete "HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender" /f

rem Enable WD services
reg add "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\SecurityHealthService" /v "Start" /t REG_DWORD /d "2" /f
reg add "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\WdBoot" /v "Start" /t REG_DWORD /d "2" /f
reg add "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\WdFilter" /v "Start" /t REG_DWORD /d "2" /f
reg add "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\WdNisDrv" /v "Start" /t REG_DWORD /d "2" /f
reg add "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\WdNisSvc" /v "Start" /t REG_DWORD /d "2" /f
reg add "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\WinDefend" /v "Start" /t REG_DWORD /d "2" /f

rem 1 - Enable Logging
reg add "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\WMI\Autologger\DefenderApiLogger" /v "Start" /t REG_DWORD /d "1" /f
reg add "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\WMI\Autologger\DefenderAuditLogger" /v "Start" /t REG_DWORD /d "1" /f

rem Enable WD Tasks
schtasks /Change /TN "Microsoft\Windows\Windows Defender\Windows Defender Cache Maintenance" /Enable
schtasks /Change /TN "Microsoft\Windows\Windows Defender\Windows Defender Cleanup" /Enable
schtasks /Change /TN "Microsoft\Windows\Windows Defender\Windows Defender Scheduled Scan" /Enable
schtasks /Change /TN "Microsoft\Windows\Windows Defender\Windows Defender Verification" /Enable

rem 1 - Potentially Unwanted Application protection (PUP) is enabled, the applications with unwanted behavior will be blocked at download and install-time
reg add "HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender\MpEngine" /v "MpEnablePus" /t REG_DWORD /d "1" /f

rem Cloud-based Protection / 0 - Disable / 1 - Basic / 2 - Advanced
reg add "HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender\SpyNet" /v "SpynetReporting" /t REG_DWORD /d "1" /f

rem Send file samples when further analysis is required / 0 - Always prompt / 1 - Send safe samples automatically / 2 - Never send / 3 - Send all samples automatically
reg add "HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender\SpyNet" /v "SubmitSamplesConsent" /t REG_DWORD /d "1" /f

rem To prevent WD using too much CPU, add this file to the exclusion list:
rem C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\MsMpEng.exe
rem reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Exclusions\Paths" /v "C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\MsMpEng.exe" /t REG_DWORD /d "0" /f

shutdown /r /t 60
```